# Wix: Checkbox to modify PATH environment variable

Tags: wix

In the Wix installer toolset, I'm trying to modify the PATH environment variable, depending on a checkbox.

Basically, the modification of PATH looks like this:

```
<Component Id='EnvVars' Guid='{8046-41E86196A926}'>
    <CreateFolder />                        
    <Environment Id='PathEnvVar'    Action='set' System='yes' Name='PATH' Part='last' Value='[APPLICATIONFOLDER]'/>                                                 
</Component>
```

I have a checkbox that looks like this:

```
<Control Id="EnvPath" Type="CheckBox" X="10" Y="83" Width="180" Height="20" Property="ENV_PATH_MODIFY" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="Add to PATH" />
```

How do I connect the checkbox to the environment variable component so that the checkbox decides whether to execute the component (which modifies the PATH var)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add install condition to your component directly

```
<Component Id='EnvVars' Guid='{8046-41E86196A926}'>
    <CreateFolder />                        
    <Environment Id='PathEnvVar'    Action='set' System='yes' Name='PATH' Part='last' Value='[APPLICATIONFOLDER]'/> 
    <Condition>
        ENV_PATH_MODIFY = 1
    </Condition>                                                
</Component>
```